# What does the number next to the skull and crossbones mean?

Tags: nintendo-wii, sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates (on the Wii in my case), when sailing there is a minimap with various symbols and numbers next to it.  The manual that comes with the game makes no mention of what these symbols/numbers mean.  I figured out most of them, but am still unsure what the number next to the skull and crossbones icon actually means.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played only the PC version, but I would guess, as an analogy to the PC version, that it details your fame, which is like a points system that ranks the pirates on a scale of pirate bad-assary.

And the following are number of crew members, remaining food supply and how happy your crew is.

Here you can see a comparison between the PC and Wii versions:

PC:
[image: image 1]

Wii:
[image: image 2]

Comment: That makes sense and seems to jive with how the number has been steadily going up throughout the game.  Thanks!